# Spring 3.1+ sources of properties (.properties, OS environment, JVM System properties), ordering and precedence?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, properties-file

I'm working on a Spring 3.1+ web application (packaged as a WAR, deployed on Tomcat) that keeps properties in a .properties file.
In my **root-servlet.xml** configuration file I have the following line

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/environment.properties" />
```

I can't get a clear understand of how Spring 3.1+ looks for properties from its potential sources of properties.

**Question Pt.1**  Am I right to think that my spring web application currently has three potential sources it will search?

1. Environment Properties (set in the Terminal/by the OS)
2. JVM System Properties (set when launching jvm using the -Dfoo=bar argument)
3. environment.properties (a file in my war classpath containing properties).

**Question Pt.2** In which order are these three property sources searched and which of the sources has the highest preference?

**Question Pt. 3** How can I configure the order in which these sources are searched and which have the highest preference?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) for the bean PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer says _Search precedence of local properties is based on the value of the localOverride property, which is by default false meaning that local properties are to be searched last, after all environment property sources._ Is that my answer?